# Problemas con el rejillas de Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy intentando poner varias columnas en bootstrap con su sistema de rejillas pero al momento de ver me muestra es siguiente problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se nota en vez de quedar abajo de gestión de redes sociales, queda es en publicidad de pago. ¿por que sucede esto? ¿Alguna solución?.

Este es mi código.

```
<!--Div Negativo 2-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 div-hacemos">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>¿Qué hacemos?</h3>
            <div class="row hacemos">
                <!-- Gestion de redes sociales -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión de redes sociales</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Creamos, gestionamos, analizamos y hacemos crecer tus redes sociales,
                            la interacción y el impacto de las comunicaciones.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Actualizamos los canales existentes y/o creamos aquellos adecuados para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- SEO -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>SEO y Link Building</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Te ayudamos a que tu página web sea encontrada en las <b>primeras páginas</b> de los buscadores.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Generamos <b>enlaces</b> con portales y páginas afines para atraer clientes y generar relevancia
                            de la marca en internet. Te asesoramos en la contratación de pautas publicitarias en portales,
                            webs de afiliaciones, etc. Creamos y publicamos contenido de calidad en tu página web (blogging)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Gestion pagina web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión página web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Mantenemos <b>actualizada</b> tu página web con contenido nuevo del hotel (nuevos servicios,
                            actualización de tarifas, descripciones, etc.), creamos banners, pop-ups, etc
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Creamos contenido</b> creativo.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Realizamos la gestión de <b>publicidad de pago</b> que mejor se adecue con las necesidades
                            de tu empresa, generando... leads (potenciales clientes) y reduciendo los costos PPC.
                            pop-ups, etc...
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Consultoría en Marketing Digital -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Consultoría en Marketing Digital</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Analizamos</b> tu posición y presencia de marca en internet.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Generamos</b> un plan de acción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Implementamos</b> el plan de acción.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño u optimización web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño u optimización web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Diseñamos o mejorar tu web para que cumpla todos los
                            estándares actuales de usabilidad, parámetros SEO y todos los
                            "gadgets" necesarios para potenciar la "conversión" (conseguir clientes)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño Gráfico -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño Gráfico</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Damos apoyo en diseño gráfico para mantener la imagen del
                            cliente actualizada y acorde a los estándares modernos
                            (logos, menús, banners, post, señalética...)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- APP -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>APP</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes y
                            generar vinculación a la marca y "UPSELLINGS".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Motor de reservas -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/comunicacion.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Motor de reservas</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Asesoría e implementación de motor de reservas.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Tenemos alcance de soluciones "stand alone" hasta
                            "integrales" que cubren todo el ciclo de venta, desde la
                            integración con el PMS, motor de reservas, channel manager,
                            revenue/yield managment hasta la pasarela de pago más adecuada
                            para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/bombilla.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Implementamos estrategias activas ON-LINE para el aumento de "reviews"
                            y evaluación de satisfacción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes ANTES de su primear
                            compra y generar "UPSELLINGS" (ventas adicionales a las previstas).
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Ejecución de campañas del uso de tu base de datos para potenciar nuevos
                            clientes y clientes "repetidores".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: existe un editor de texto para agregar código.

Comment: @ReneLimon Si lo se, pero el codigo era muy largo para lo que realmente queria mostrar que son los divs.

Comment: parece ser poco código. Revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Listo tome tu consejo, gracias @ReneLimon

Answer (score 1):

@JuanCarlosPeñaM. recuerda que boostrap siempre en sus regillas tiene 12 columnas por cada row y podrias poner de esta forma.

```html
<!--Div Negativo 2-->
<div class="row">
   
        <div class="container">
            <h3>¿Qué hacemos?</h3>
            <div class="row hacemos">
                <!-- Gestion de redes sociales -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión de redes sociales</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Creamos, gestionamos, analizamos y hacemos crecer tus redes sociales,
                            la interacción y el impacto de las comunicaciones.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Actualizamos los canales existentes y/o creamos aquellos adecuados para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- SEO -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>SEO y Link Building</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Te ayudamos a que tu página web sea encontrada en las <b>primeras páginas</b> de los buscadores.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Generamos <b>enlaces</b> con portales y páginas afines para atraer clientes y generar relevancia
                            de la marca en internet. Te asesoramos en la contratación de pautas publicitarias en portales,
                            webs de afiliaciones, etc. Creamos y publicamos contenido de calidad en tu página web (blogging)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Gestion pagina web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión página web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Mantenemos <b>actualizada</b> tu página web con contenido nuevo del hotel (nuevos servicios,
                            actualización de tarifas, descripciones, etc.), creamos banners, pop-ups, etc
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Creamos contenido</b> creativo.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Realizamos la gestión de <b>publicidad de pago</b> que mejor se adecue con las necesidades
                            de tu empresa, generando... leads (potenciales clientes) y reduciendo los costos PPC.
                            pop-ups, etc...
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <!-- Consultoría en Marketing Digital -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Consultoría en Marketing Digital</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Analizamos</b> tu posición y presencia de marca en internet.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Generamos</b> un plan de acción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Implementamos</b> el plan de acción.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño u optimización web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño u optimización web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Diseñamos o mejorar tu web para que cumpla todos los
                            estándares actuales de usabilidad, parámetros SEO y todos los
                            "gadgets" necesarios para potenciar la "conversión" (conseguir clientes)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño Gráfico -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño Gráfico</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Damos apoyo en diseño gráfico para mantener la imagen del
                            cliente actualizada y acorde a los estándares modernos
                            (logos, menús, banners, post, señalética...)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- APP -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>APP</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes y
                            generar vinculación a la marca y "UPSELLINGS".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <!-- Motor de reservas -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/comunicacion.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Motor de reservas</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Asesoría e implementación de motor de reservas.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Tenemos alcance de soluciones "stand alone" hasta
                            "integrales" que cubren todo el ciclo de venta, desde la
                            integración con el PMS, motor de reservas, channel manager,
                            revenue/yield managment hasta la pasarela de pago más adecuada
                            para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/bombilla.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Implementamos estrategias activas ON-LINE para el aumento de "reviews"
                            y evaluación de satisfacción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes ANTES de su primear
                            compra y generar "UPSELLINGS" (ventas adicionales a las previstas).
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Ejecución de campañas del uso de tu base de datos para potenciar nuevos
                            clientes y clientes "repetidores".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregando estas lineas entre los diferentes etiquetas `<div>` que se distorcionan

```
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
    <!--Div Negativo 2-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 div-hacemos">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>¿Qué hacemos?</h3>
            <div class="row hacemos">
                <!-- Gestion de redes sociales -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión de redes sociales</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Creamos, gestionamos, analizamos y hacemos crecer tus redes sociales,
                            la interacción y el impacto de las comunicaciones.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Actualizamos los canales existentes y/o creamos aquellos adecuados para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- SEO -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>SEO y Link Building</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Te ayudamos a que tu página web sea encontrada en las <b>primeras páginas</b> de los buscadores.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Generamos <b>enlaces</b> con portales y páginas afines para atraer clientes y generar relevancia
                            de la marca en internet. Te asesoramos en la contratación de pautas publicitarias en portales,
                            webs de afiliaciones, etc. Creamos y publicamos contenido de calidad en tu página web (blogging)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Gestion pagina web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión página web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Mantenemos <b>actualizada</b> tu página web con contenido nuevo del hotel (nuevos servicios,
                            actualización de tarifas, descripciones, etc.), creamos banners, pop-ups, etc
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

                <!-- Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Creamos contenido</b> creativo.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Realizamos la gestión de <b>publicidad de pago</b> que mejor se adecue con las necesidades
                            de tu empresa, generando... leads (potenciales clientes) y reduciendo los costos PPC.
                            pop-ups, etc...
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block clearfix visible-md-block clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

                <!-- Consultoría en Marketing Digital -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Consultoría en Marketing Digital</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Analizamos</b> tu posición y presencia de marca en internet.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Generamos</b> un plan de acción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Implementamos</b> el plan de acción.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño u optimización web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño u optimización web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Diseñamos o mejorar tu web para que cumpla todos los
                            estándares actuales de usabilidad, parámetros SEO y todos los
                            "gadgets" necesarios para potenciar la "conversión" (conseguir clientes)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño Gráfico -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño Gráfico</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Damos apoyo en diseño gráfico para mantener la imagen del
                            cliente actualizada y acorde a los estándares modernos
                            (logos, menús, banners, post, señalética...)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- APP -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>APP</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes y
                            generar vinculación a la marca y "UPSELLINGS".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block clearfix visible-md-block clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

                <!-- Motor de reservas -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/comunicacion.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Motor de reservas</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Asesoría e implementación de motor de reservas.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Tenemos alcance de soluciones "stand alone" hasta
                            "integrales" que cubren todo el ciclo de venta, desde la
                            integración con el PMS, motor de reservas, channel manager,
                            revenue/yield managment hasta la pasarela de pago más adecuada
                            para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/bombilla.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Implementamos estrategias activas ON-LINE para el aumento de "reviews"
                            y evaluación de satisfacción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes ANTES de su primear
                            compra y generar "UPSELLINGS" (ventas adicionales a las previstas).
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Ejecución de campañas del uso de tu base de datos para potenciar nuevos
                            clientes y clientes "repetidores".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajusté la clase de una etiqueta  que contenía un col-md-offset-3 y agregué en diferentes partes del código la clase clearfix. Para mas información, consulta este video [Curso completo de Bootstrap 2.- La Grid, entendiendo el sistema de rejillas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gch7gnnRRs&index=2&list=PLhSj3UTs2_yWTKvu1Aq3xUhzIJNBZ3MFW) de Falcon Masters el explica muy bien este tipo de situaciones en bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Las rejillas de `Bootstrap` son de **12 celdas**. En el código que muestras tienes alrededor de 11 en una sola fila (**`row`**). Trata de separarlo por varias filas (**`row`**).

Además estás definiendo con espacio 3,4 y 6 cada etiqueta **`div`**, y si multiplicas las cantidades de **`div`** que tienes dentro de `<div class="row hacemos">` **no es igual a 12**.
 Siempre,

> siempre ese cálculo debe darte 12

Comment: Intente hacer eso y no encuentro lo que quiero, y es que en el caso que este en col-sm y quiera poner 3 columnas en cada una de las filas pero como esta encerrada en un row, me queda 3 arriba, 1 abajo y sigue el siguiente row. Entonces no es lo que busco

Answer (score 0):

No creo que se pueda arreglar agregando la clase `.row` y haciendo separaciones, lo único que se me ocurre es limitar el tamaño del `div` con clase `.col-x-x` y agregar un `scroll`

```css
.row > div.servicios{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--Div Negativo 2-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 div-hacemos">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>¿Qué hacemos?</h3>
            <div class="row hacemos">
                <!-- Gestion de redes sociales -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión de redes sociales</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Creamos, gestionamos, analizamos y hacemos crecer tus redes sociales,
                            la interacción y el impacto de las comunicaciones.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Actualizamos los canales existentes y/o creamos aquellos adecuados para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- SEO -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>SEO y Link Building</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Te ayudamos a que tu página web sea encontrada en las <b>primeras páginas</b> de los buscadores.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Generamos <b>enlaces</b> con portales y páginas afines para atraer clientes y generar relevancia
                            de la marca en internet. Te asesoramos en la contratación de pautas publicitarias en portales,
                            webs de afiliaciones, etc. Creamos y publicamos contenido de calidad en tu página web (blogging)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Gestion pagina web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Gestión página web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Mantenemos <b>actualizada</b> tu página web con contenido nuevo del hotel (nuevos servicios,
                            actualización de tarifas, descripciones, etc.), creamos banners, pop-ups, etc
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Publicidad de pago (SEM y SMM)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Creamos contenido</b> creativo.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Realizamos la gestión de <b>publicidad de pago</b> que mejor se adecue con las necesidades
                            de tu empresa, generando... leads (potenciales clientes) y reduciendo los costos PPC.
                            pop-ups, etc...
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Consultoría en Marketing Digital -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/manos.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Consultoría en Marketing Digital</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <b>Analizamos</b> tu posición y presencia de marca en internet.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Generamos</b> un plan de acción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <b>Implementamos</b> el plan de acción.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño u optimización web -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" >
                    <img src="img/icons/bocina.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño u optimización web</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Diseñamos o mejorar tu web para que cumpla todos los
                            estándares actuales de usabilidad, parámetros SEO y todos los
                            "gadgets" necesarios para potenciar la "conversión" (conseguir clientes)
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- Diseño Gráfico -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/rayo.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Diseño Gráfico</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Damos apoyo en diseño gráfico para mantener la imagen del
                            cliente actualizada y acorde a los estándares modernos
                            (logos, menús, banners, post, señalética...)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sincronizamos tu página web con el contenido del plan de comunicación.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
                <!-- APP -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/computer.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>APP</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes y
                            generar vinculación a la marca y "UPSELLINGS".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Motor de reservas -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-offset-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/comunicacion.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>Motor de reservas</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Asesoría e implementación de motor de reservas.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Tenemos alcance de soluciones "stand alone" hasta
                            "integrales" que cubren todo el ciclo de venta, desde la
                            integración con el PMS, motor de reservas, channel manager,
                            revenue/yield managment hasta la pasarela de pago más adecuada
                            para el cliente.
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes) -->
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="img/icons/bombilla.png" alt="" class="icon">
                    <h4>CRM y Mail marketing (Gestión de la relación con los clientes)</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Implementamos estrategias activas ON-LINE para el aumento de "reviews"
                            y evaluación de satisfacción.
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Sistema para potenciar la interacción con los clientes ANTES de su primear
                            compra y generar "UPSELLINGS" (ventas adicionales a las previstas).
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Ejecución de campañas del uso de tu base de datos para potenciar nuevos
                            clientes y clientes "repetidores".
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="servicios col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Miralo en Ampliar, y veras que tampoco es la mejor solucion, y si pongo en max-heigth a tamaño de escritorio, cuando lo pase a responsivo se ver espacios MUY GRANDE.

Comment: @JuanCarlosPeñaM. osea que tu buscas que la rejilla que va en la linea de bajo este empezando donde termina la de arriba, si es así, con `bootstrap` no se respeta eso que buscas, por lo tanto se genera un espacio